# How to get the embed webview for iOS Facebook Login

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to get the access of the webview of Facebook login.

In viewcontroller A:

```
FBLoginView* loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:
                          @[@"public_profile", @"rsvp_event"]];

// Force to use embeded webview
loginView.loginBehavior = FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView;

loginView.delegate = self;

// Align the button in the center horizontally
loginView.frame = CGRectOffset(XXXXXXXXX);

[self.view addSubview:loginView];
```

And after user press the login button, it will show a embed webview to let user login.

My question is how to get the access to that webview?

I tried:

```
for (id obj in self.loginView.subviews) {
    NSLog(@"%@", obj);

}
```

It only contain a button and a fb shadow label.

I also tried:

```
for (id obj in [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view.subviews) {
    NSLog(@"%@", obj);
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]]) {
        // NO obj is UIWebview
        break;
    }
}
```

And still not get the webview. Only get UINavigationTransitionView and UIViewControllerWrapperView

How to get the webview?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using a webview for login? Why not use the Facebook SDK?

Comment: It's also from Facebook SDK. The webview is auto-create by FBLoginView. Just set the login behavior to FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView. I have some reasons that I must need to use this login behavior.

Comment: If you explain your reason it is easier to help you

Comment: No matter what reason it is, the problem is how to get the reference of the webview. I will not use any other login method here. So what I need is to get the reference of webview instead of using another method. Thus, the reason is not matter. Thanks.

Comment: The reason matter because maybe there is some other way to solve it.

Comment: What I need is a method to get the webview of THIS login behavior. maybe there is other ways to do the same thing, but that is not I need.

Comment: OK good luck with finding someone to help you